# ANTLR 4 how to parse comments

Tags: antlr4

I am parsing a SQL like language and I am having trouble parsing comments.
The idea is to ignore them.

I have these rules:

```
NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n' -> skip 
WS  :    [ \t]+ -> skip
```

How can I ignore:

- Everything that is between '--'or '#' and the next '\n'
- Everything between '/*' and '*/'  (slash + asterisk untill asterix + slash - the asterisk somehow gone).

I tried something like this before the WS and the NEWLINW:

```
COMMENT1 : ('--'|'#') ~'\n'* -> skip;
```

didn't work - I got:

```
line 1:115 missing ';' at '<EOF>'
```

probably something because it didn't go with my main rule:
parse : (statments (';')+)* EOF;

Can anyone help me?

Regards idob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When in doubt, see what someone else did ;)

[There are some ready-made grammars for different languages](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4), more or less working.

So I look in Java's grammar and see:

```
COMMENT
: '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip
;
LINE_COMMENT
: '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip
;
```

So your general idea seems to be correct. I'm guessing that the problem lies somewhere else. Can you provide sample input you test on and your grammar (relevant parts)?